# Cannot find a database provider with the invariant name MySql.Data.MySqlClient - Power Apps

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector, powerapps

I'm going to connect my MySQL server to Microsoft Power Apps. But I have some problems.

In Power Apps, I select **Connections** and then searsch for **MySQL** and select it.

[image]

I have the following installed:

- On-Premises data gateway
- MySQL Connector NET
- MySQL Server 8.0
- MySQL Workbench 8.0

And then I get the problem.

> Cannot find a database provider with the invariant name
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient. inner exception: Cannot find a database
> provider with the invariant name MySql.Data.MySqlClient.
> clientRequestId: e3bf2ac6-2cd1-4b24-b27a-879b161015b4

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solved the issue:

I installed MySQL Installer 8.0.28. Now it's working.

I recently had installed the latest MySQL Installer 8.0.33. It is a bug in the 33-version.

Comment: still an existing issue at v8.0.33.1

Comment: Additional context: a bug was first introduced in 8.0.29 (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=107316) and fixed in 8.0.31. The functionality then broke again in 8.0.33 (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=110975) and is unfixed as of now. Versions .28, .31, and .32 are functional.

Answer (score 1):

Today I have encountered the same problem with 8.0.33 on a new Win 11 PC. The problem got solved by downgrading to MySQL Connector 8.0.28. Thanks.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34682704)